# Stored Procedure Results from User-defined Table Variable not Read by SqlDataReader

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ado.net

I have the following `t-sql` stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE myProcedure

DECLARE @retTab myTab;

MERGE
...
OUTPUT carrierId INTO @retTab;

SELECT * FROM @retTab;
```

where `myTab` is a user-defined table type which looks something like this:

```
CREATE TYPE myTab AS TABLE (
    carrierId INT       
);
```

When I execute the procedure directly in Management Studio, I get the data result set; however when I execute it using ADO.NET as follows:

```
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("spMergeCoverage", con))
{
     cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
     ...
     using (SqlDataReader r = cmd.ExecuteReader())
     {      
         while (r.Read())
         {
             var id = (int)r["carrierId"];
         ...
```

my `SqlDataReader` gets an empty result set. Also, when I insert the `merge` output into a real table as opposed to `@retTab`, my reader gets the results. Why is this happening and how do I fix this?

Comment: Could you post the c# code?

Comment: Why do you ExecuteNonQuery?

Comment: Because I'm running a stored procedure?

Comment: What should I use instead?

Comment: Just remove that line: cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(). You use execute non query when you don't need a reader. The function's name is very descriptive. NonQuery = no reader - it inserts, updates, and deletes.

Comment: Yeah, ExecuteNonQuery and ExecuteReader are both attempts to execute the SqlCommand you've set up.  ExecuteNonQuery shouldn't be used when you're expecting a result set back.

Comment: Copied that idiom from cases where I'm getting output parameters as well as a result set from the stored procedure.

Comment: Anyway, commenting out that line did not make a difference.

Comment: Then please post the new code since you know that the current code here is definitely wrong. Also, the way you read data is important to see.

Comment: Why do you have .... after command.StoredProcedure?, please post more code

Answer (score -1):

If there are other DML operations in the stored procedure (like the merge/output statement), and NOCOUNT is set to off, then each DML operation will send a result set back to the caller, even if it is just "X records affected", it will show up as an empty result set in the sqldatareader. Try putting

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
```

At the top of the proc, and then set it back to off at the end, and see if you get the expected results.

Comment: I know I'm getting the results from the final query, `select * from @retTab` because the column name of the reader is `carrierId`; it's just that it returns 0 rows.